# System process using CPU while lid is closed

Tags: windows-8, laptop, cpu-usage

I'm running Windows 8.1 on my laptop, and it is set to do nothing when the lid is closed.

However, I often notice that the fan gets very loud, and when I open the laptop I can see CPU usage suddenly drop from 70% to almost nothing. It seems that System process is using 30%+ CPU while the lid is closed, and then suddenly stops when I open it. What could cause this behavior?

Comment: any update? can you confirm this or do you need help looking at the ETL?

Answer (score 1):

To capture a trace of the CPU usage. Install the [WPT from Win10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), open a cmd.exe as admin and run this command:

```
xperf -on latency -stackwalk profile -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\highCPUUsage.etl
```

Now do the action that triggers the CPU usage of the system process. When you see the issue, wait 30s, open the lid, go to the cmd.exe and press a key to stop logging.

My guess is that during [analyzing the ETL file with WPA](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) it will show, that the CPU usage comes from `ntoskrnl.exe!MiScrubMemoryWorker` and you'll see something like this:

```
Line #, DPC/ISR, Process, Stack Tag, Stack, Count, TimeStamp (s), % Weight
8, , , ,    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!MiScrubMemoryWorker, 79667, , 12,45
9, , , ,    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!MiScrubNode, 79667, , 12,45
10, , , ,   |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!MiScrubNodeLargePages, 79667, , 12,45
11, , , ,   |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!MiScrubNodeLargePageList, 79667, , 12,45
12, , , ,   |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!MiScrubPage, 79663, , 12,45
13, , , ,   |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!RtlScrubMemory, 79653, , 12,45
14, , , ,   |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpGenericRandomPatternWorker, 38549, , 6,02
```

This is a function to test the memory for errors by filling / reading some patterns (`ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpGenericRandomPatternWorker`).

This is by design and happens when the idle maintenance task kicks up when your device is idle.

To stop it, use [Task Scheduler and disable the idle maintenance task](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-2120194/enable-disable-automatic-maintenance-windows.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it next time I'm on my laptop. So you reckon its just testing memory while idle?

Comment: I've asked this Microsoft when I saw it the first time so I now know what the function does.